# SQL unknown column in where clause

Tags: sql, string-constant

I get this error:

```
Error: UPDATE stats SET stat2='2' WHERE name=views
Unknown column 'views' in 'where clause'
```

In the table 'name' is the column, and 'views' is a value in that column.

As far as I can tell from the documentation the statement "WHERE name=views" should be read as "WHERE {column}={cell value}", whereas the error is inferring that the column name is the second value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put the values within `''` since it's a string value

```
UPDATE stats SET stat2='2' WHERE name='views'
```

Comment: @IsaacWestenra,, if it helped you please mark it as accepted